# /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash file missing after reinstall of kinetic

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, setup.bash, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04
I had ROS Kinetic installed [following the tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu) and it was working. I was experiencing errors with a tutorial, [covered here](http://answers.ros.org/question/257331/python-module-empy-missing-tutorials/), so I removed ROS in order to do a complete fresh install. I did so by using:

```
sudo apt-get remove ros-kinetic-desktop-full 
sudo apt-get remove python-rosinstall
sudo rm -fr /etc/ros
sudo rm -fr /opt/ros
sudo rm -fr ~/.ros
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

To purge my system of my first ROS install.

I then reapplied all the directions given in the [installation tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu).

It seems however the the 'setup.bash' file is not installed the second time around. When I `ls /opt/ros/kinetic` I get only the following:

```
philglau@phil-glau-ubuntu-16:/opt/ros/kinetic$ ls
bin  etc  include  lib  share
```

**The 'setup.bash' script is missing !!** (using `du -hs` indicates there are 145MB of other files in this /kinetic folder, so it's not like it didn't install most of the stuff.) Furthermore, when I installed the second time, it gave absolutely no errors or warning to indicate that something was missing or wrong.

This is from `dpkg -l`

```
philglau@phil-glau-ubuntu-16:~$ dpkg -l | grep ros-kinetic-catkin
ii  ros-kinetic-catkin                           0.7.6-0xenial-20170217-212821-0800                    amd64        Low-level build system macros and infrastructure for RO
```

Can't figure out why this is. Did I do something incorrect when uninstalling the original version like forget some other cache or directory??

Is it possible to just manually install the missing setup.bash script? If so where would I get it?

Thank you in advance for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257332//opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash-file-missing-after-reinstall-of-kinetic/) by [philglau](https://answers.ros.org/users/6271/philglau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 248 on 2017-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> sudo apt-get remove ros-kinetic-desktop-full
> ```

```
...
sudo rm -fr /opt/ros
...
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Not sure, but it could be that `apt` did not remove `ros-kinetic-catkin` with the `autoremove`, and then when you installed everything the second time, dependency resolution determined that the *package* `ros-kinetic-catkin` was already installed, so it skipped it.

But because you `rm -fr /opt/ros` before, the *files* are not actually there anymore.

Can you check whether a `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-kinetic-catkin` gets the files back?

---

Btw: I would never (well, never ..) `rm -rf` files or directories that were installed by a package manager. Use `apt-get remove` or `apt-get purge` with a regex or a package list. If there are still files left after running that, *then* removing them manually could be acceptable.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [philglau](https://answers.ros.org/users/6271/philglau/) on 2017-03-19**:
Thank you for the advice regarding using `remove` and `purge`. I will use that going forward.
I ran `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-kinetic-catkin` and it does appear to have placed the missing files into `/opt/ros/kinetic/`. Thank you.

**Comment by [philglau](https://answers.ros.org/users/6271/philglau/) on 2017-03-19**:
I should have been clearer above I had actually run `sudo apt autoremove` prior to running the `rm -fr` commands. After running `sudo apt autoremove`, I was still left with a `/opt/ros/kenetic/` directory, that was mostly empty except for folders, thus the `rm -fr` to get rid of final remnants.

**Comment by [luisfelipewb](https://answers.ros.org/users/38420/luisfelipewb/) on 2018-11-07**:
More than on year later, I had exactly the same problem and the same solution worked for me :) Thanks!